# Can ggplot format points with '<' values on-the-fly or do I need a separate data column?

Tags: ggplot2, formatting, point, evaluate

How can I handle LOQ values in ggplot?
I would like to use the original data:

| Parameter | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Fe | <2 |
| Fe | 12 |
| Fe | 7 |

and just mark the <-values in some way, either with a "<" or a different colour.

I realize that having a "<" turns my numeric data into string data. Is there a way to convert and format the plotted point on-the-fly, or must I create a supplementary column with the <-value? I guess formatting the individual <-point in the plot will require a separate column anyways? And perhaps ggplot cannot evaluate each individual value to check for "<"?

Comment: In almost every case, it is much faster and 'cleaner' to modify your data prior to plotting rather than finding an on-the-fly solution. I'd recommend creating a numeric version of the "Concentration" column e.g. strip out the <. You can then subset the original "Concentration" column to `geom_text()`  your < values. Or create another "colour_id" column that has the same value for all < values. This assumes that it is convention in your field of study to plot a < value in a fixed position. In others words, is it OK to plot <2 at 2 even though <2 falls anywhere between -Inf and 2?

Comment: Ok, I will have to try this out. I think creating a subset with only the <-values, and then adding them on top of the existing plot but with a different point colour, could work nicely in my case. Not sure it's the prettiest solution though, but I have quite small data sets (ca 12-36 points/plot) so I should be ok. i choose to plot the actiual <-value, since this is the easiest way to describe the data. "Red dots indicate <-values" is better than "Red dots indicate half of the <-values".

Comment: Speaking of which - how can I calculate a new numeric value from the <-value? For example, I want to replace all <x with y*x. Do I have to use a loop for this, or can it be done quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to post answer here rather than comment. I've added two columns using base R to give you a couple of options:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(Parameter = "Fe",
                 Concentration = c("<2", 7, 12, 5, 10, 11, 6, 4, 8, <3, "13"))

# Create integer copy of Concentration
df$LOQ <- as.integer(gsub("<", "", df$Concentration))
# Create column to identify < integers
df$less_than <- ifelse(grepl("^<", df$Concentration), "<", NA)

# Use new columns to plot data and identify < values
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Parameter, y = LOQ)) +
  geom_text(data = df, aes(x = Parameter, y = LOQ, 
                           label = less_than,
                           colour = "red"),
            hjust = -1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Note that the `ggplot()` function will throw this warning:

> Warning message: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).

You can safely ignore this, it just means the NA values in the "less_than" column were ignored by `ggplot2`. And the result:

[image: result]

If you want to plot the < values using a different colour, change the values in the "less_than" column to something like the example below:

```
# Create column to identify < integers
df$less_than <- ifelse(grepl("^<", df$Concentration), "<", "=")

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Parameter, y = LOQ, colour = less_than)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Result:

[image: result2]